# Updating a large number of entities in a datastore on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore

I would like to perform a small operation on all entities of a specific kind and rewrite them to the datastore. I currently have 20,000 entities of this kind but would like a solution that would scale to any amount.

What are my options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [mapper](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/GettingStartedInPython) - this is part of the MapReduce framework, but you only want the first component, map, as you don't need the shuffle/reduce step if you're simply mutating datastore entities.

Comment: I'm actually already using the MapReduce framework so pipelining these operations seem like a good idea. My concern is to have many many single put() operations running in parallel. beyond the performance issue I'm worried about datastore timeouts since many entities share entity groups. Is there anyway to pipeline and still aggregate put()s?

Comment: the map-reduce api allows for batch datastore operations via a mutation pool. http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/GettingStartedInPython

Answer (score 3):

Daniel is correct, but if you don't want to mess up with the mapper, that requires you to add another library to your app you can do it using [Task Queues](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) or even simpler using the [deferred library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred) that is included since SDK 1.2.3.

20.000 entities it's not that dramatic and I assume that this task is not going be performed in regular basis (but even if it does, it is feasible).

Here is an example using [NDB](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries) and the deferred library (you can easily do that using DB, but consider switching to NDB anyway if you are not already using it). It's a pretty straight forward way, but without caring much about the timeouts:

```
def update_model(limit=1000):
  more_cursor = None
  more = True
  while more:
    model_dbs, more_cursor, more = Model.query().fetch_page(limit, start_cursor=more_cursor)
    for model_db in model_dbs:
      model_db.updated = True
    ndb.put_multi(model_dbs)
    logging.info('### %d entities were updated' % len(model_dbs))

class UpdateModelHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    deferred.defer(update_model, _queue='queue')
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write('The task has been started!')
```

Comment: My main concern regarding this approach is hitting the instance memory limit since all models are stored in memory prior to writing (i've had these before). It's possible to have the update_model task spawn another update_model task after a given number of models by passing a cursor and so on.

Comment: @TomerWeller I don't think that is necessary, this is not an intrusive test and it's very easy to adopt it to your own app.. so give it a shot and let us know

Comment: "Exceeded soft private memory limit with 155.32 MB after servicing 1 requests total". I have 18,000 entities averaging at 10KB  per entity. This is an expected failure since the basic frontend instance has 128MB of Memory and I'm trying to load 180MB worth of data. It's nice of appengine to let me get to 155 :)

Comment: @TomerWeller if you go to Application Settings you are able to increase it up to 512MB of memory.. http://i.imgur.com/BZ4AN.png

Comment: Which will limit the number of entities to 51k. This approach does not allow horizontal scaling.

Comment: I do understand.. Like I said.. if it's something that you just have to do once and not doing it in regular basis, you can try it.. otherwise you have to try other methods..